# Getting Access is denied while connecting with restful backend in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am getting following error:

> "Error: Access is denied.\r\n\n   at Anonymous function (eval code:1343:17)\n   at Observable.prototype.subscribe (eval code:52:9)\n   at Observable.prototype._subscribe (eval code:109:9)\n   at MapOperator.prototype.call (eval code:54:9)\n   at Observable.prototype.subscribe (eval code:52:9)\n   at Observable.prototype._subscribe (eval code:109:9)\n   at CatchOperator.prototype.call (eval code:29:9)\n   at Observable.prototype.subscribe (eval code:52:9)\n   at SearchCustomerComponent.prototype.onSearch (eval code:21:9)\n   at _View_SearchCustomerComponent0.prototype._handle_ngSubmit_2_0 (Function code:232:3)"

Here is my code:

```js
// searchCustomer.component.ts 
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomerAcct } from '../models/customer-acct';
import { CustomerService } from '../services/customer.service';

@Component ({
    selector: 'search-customer',
    templateUrl: './app/customer/SearchCustomer.component.html'

})

export class SearchCustomerComponent {

    errorMessage: string;
    ca: CustomerAcct;
    mode = 'Observable';
    custAcctNo: number;

    constructor (private customerService: CustomerService) {}

    onSearch(scf: NgForm){

        console.log("custAcctNo = ", this.custAcctNo);
        this.customerService.getCustomer(this.custAcctNo).subscribe(
            data => this.ca = data,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        console.log("this.ca ", this.ca.customerAcctId);
    }

}




// customer.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CustomerAcct } from '../models/customer-acct';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    private backendURL = 'localhost:8080/BAG';

    getCustomer(custAcct: number): Observable<CustomerAcct> {
        // let custURL = this.backendURL.concat('customer/findCustomer');
        let custURL = 'localhost:8080/BAG/customer/findCustomer';
        return this.http.get(custURL)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        // Response object holds data into JSON object, so need to parse it using res.json() method.
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || { };
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        // TO DO use a remort logging infrastructure 
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : 
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
            console.error(errMsg); 
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- SerachCustomer.component.html -->
<div>
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSearch(searchCustomer)" #searchCustomer="ngForm">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" 
                                        class="form-control"
                                        id="custAcctNo" 
                                        placeholder="Search Customer Acct..." 
                                        [(ngModel)]="this.custAcctNo"
                                        name="custAcctNo" required>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
                                </span>
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your web server is running on port 8080?

Comment: Yes, Here is the log from Tomcat:

Comment: 2016-09-12 19:21:18.852[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6024[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)

Comment: Finally it is solved. Silly silly mistakes. I did not have "http://" in url string. Once added, it started working.